# Entity Framework Won't Include() all Tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got a simple set of 3 tables that EF knows are related...

[image: Lexicon<=>LexiconTerms]

[image: Local<=>LexiconTerms]

In my repository I execute the following...

```
var result = localContext.LexiconTerms.Include(i=>i.Locale).Include(i=>i.Lexicon)
```

When I examine the results Lexicon is always populated and Locale is always `null`

Now, if I look at the SQL generated I see this ...

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[LexiconId] AS [LexiconId], 
    [Extent1].[ResourceId] AS [ResourceId], 
    [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value], 
    [Extent1].[LocaleId] AS [LocaleId], 
    [Extent1].[ResourceSet] AS [ResourceSet], 
    [Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Extent1].[BinFile] AS [BinFile], 
    [Extent1].[TextFile] AS [TextFile], 
    [Extent1].[Filename] AS [Filename], 
    [Extent1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
    [Extent1].[ValueType] AS [ValueType], 
    [Extent1].[Updated] AS [Updated], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent2].[LocaleCode] AS [LocaleCode], 
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    [Extent3].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent3].[DeletedOn] AS [DeletedOn]
    FROM   [Locale].[LexiconTerms] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [Locale].[Locale] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[LocaleId] = [Extent2].[LocaleCode]
    INNER JOIN [Locale].[Lexicon] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[LexiconId] = [Extent3].[Id]
    WHERE (N'Test1' = [Extent1].[ResourceId]) AND (N'UnitTest' = [Extent1].[ResourceSet]) AND (-2 = [Extent1].[LexiconId]) AND ([Extent1].[LocaleId] = @p__linq__0)
```

Which clearly demonstrates that EF is fetching the data. Further, running the SQL in SSMS, I can see all the appropriate values for all 3 of the tables...

[image: SQL Results]

So, what am I doing/not doing that is preventing EF populating the one related object and not the other?

I know I can get over this issue by, for example, creating a view, but I'm trying to understand what it is that EF is doing.

**EDIT:**
I'm using Database First in EF. These are the classes that EF has generated...

```
public partial class Lexicon
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Lexicon()
    {
        this.LexiconTerms = new HashSet<LexiconTerm>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeletedOn { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<LexiconTerm> LexiconTerms { get; set; }
}

public partial class LexiconTerm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LexiconId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string LocaleId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceSet { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public byte[] BinFile { get; set; }
    public string TextFile { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int ValueType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Updated { get; set; }

    public virtual Lexicon Lexicon { get; set; }
    public virtual Locale Locale { get; set; }
}

public partial class Locale
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Locale()
    {
        this.LexiconTerms = new HashSet<LexiconTerm>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LocaleCode { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<LexiconTerm> LexiconTerms { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Code First approach? Can you show your entity classes?

Comment: Are your navigation properties marked `virtual`? To be honest, I think it is only for lazy loading, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: I've updated the Q to show the classes used.

Comment: Does EF know that `Locale.LocaleCode` is the primary key?

Comment: @YacoubMassad. I believe so; it is marked as the Entity Key as you can see in the first couple of images. is there some other, additional, way of informing EF of this?

Comment: are LexiconTerm.LocaleId and Locale.LocaleCode of the same type? you see the join is done on these attributes (FK correction shouldn't be important however, but you can adjust this using Fluent API in your modelBuilder or Data Annotations in your Business Objects)

Comment: @StuartHemming What is your LazyLoading setting value?  Also, EF has a habit of only loading Child objects when they are first accessed.  To get around this DB First problem, I actually migrated away from the Model approach to a more granular approach utilizing [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Comment: @GoldBishop. TBH I'm getting the same results whether or not LazyLoading is enabled.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, Yup. They're both NVARCHAR(10)

Comment: hehehehe, @StuartHemming, append to the end of your statement, `toList()` and see what happens.

Comment: The only slightly unexpected thing I see is the negative Ids, but that shouldn't be a problem, normally.

Answer (score 1):

You use eagerly loading so You need to change your code like this.

```
var result = localContext.LexiconTerms.Include(i=>i.Locale.Lexicon)
```

OR

```
var result = localContext.LexiconTerms.Include("Locale.Lexicon")
```

It is useful document

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx